# How can I not react to blur event on YUI autocomplete select

Tags: javascript, events, autocomplete, onblur, yui-autocomplete

I am trying to react diffrently to onBlur and onSelect events with YUI autocomplete. I need to hide the AC, when the user clicks somewhere else and leave it there on select. The problem is, that a blur event is fired onSelect as well. I could not find an event which is triggered only when clicking outside the AC and I am really stuck catching the blur event in some way in case of select since it is fired before the select event.

So basically what I want is an output like:

> click outside ac: BLUR
>
> select value: SELECT val

But what I am getting is:

> click outside ac: BLUR
>
> select value: BLUR, SELECT val

Which leads to a hidden AC on select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the blur event fires when you select something, and it's likely that you won't be able to prevent that, on blur set a timeout. If the timer times out, then do what you would normally do on blur.

In the select event, cancel the timer.

Some very loose pseudo code:

```
var blurTimer = null;

function handleBlur() {
    blurTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        // do what you normally do onblur
    }, 50);
}

function handleSelect() {
    clearTimeout(blurTimer);

    // do what you normaly do on select
}
```